# SpringBoot simple multipart file upload with Advanced rest client (Chrome)

Tags: spring, rest, file-upload, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I want to upload a image to the file system. So I am using *Multi-part file upload with spring boot.* And also I am using Advance Rest Client(Chrome) tool to `POST` *Multi part file*. But I am facing an error even I do not specify any content type ***org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found.***

> Here my rest controller code,

```
@RestController
public class StringController {
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String singleSave(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){

    String fileName = null;
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream buffStream = 
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("F:/" + fileName)));
            buffStream.write(bytes);
            buffStream.close();
            return "You have successfully uploaded " + fileName;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + fileName + ": " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "Unable to upload. File is empty.";
    }
  }
}
```

> Screenshot (Advance rest client tool)

[image]

> Error

*`{
"timestamp": 1490678908517,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException",
"message": "Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found",
"path": "/upload"
}`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your request from advance rest client. It is working fine in the postman.The image is getting uploaded. Try with postman you will get it.

Comment: yep brother Its worked. Thank you for your kind response. But may i know why its not working in advance rest client??

Answer (score 0):

You lost in you client request headers value **boundary**.
Construct in PostMan header "Content-Type" like this:

```
Content-Type : multipart/form-data;boundary="12312313132132"
```